# Why does <input type='date'> CANNOT work in Dart

Tags: dart

I have posted previous questions regarding

```
<input type='date'>
```

It was subsequently reported to be fixed but again attempting to use it crashes Chromium.

Is it possible to fix this issue?

If someone has gotten it to work, I would be very happy to see the solution. I need a datepicker but none is avalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old Chrome bug which was fixed in Chrome a while back. 
The current Dartium version is based on an old Chrome that still contains this bug.

Dartium is currently being reworked to automate future updates and a new version is expected to land soon - hopefully in one of the next 1.15.0-dev versions.

Comment: I hope the problem will be solved once and for all. This problem has been around for far too long. There have been so many changes in Dart, yet this basic one exist.

Comment: Todays bleeding edge Dart version is already shipped with Dartium based on Chromium 45.

Comment: Just came out in 1.15-dev3. Confirmed your date issue here works with that sdk version.